# Weird rendering artefact in vim (terminal, not MacVim)

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, rendering

Running Mac OS X, using either Terminal.app or iTerm2, there is a strange artefact with the character rendering that I have a hard time explaining and an even harder time understanding. I'll start with a video of my screen so that you can see and example of it in action:

[image: Strange terminal vim rendering]

From the video you can see a few ways it is weird, for example, sometimes when I hit a letter in insert mode, the character is double printed. When I go into normal mode, the artefact remains. When I re-enter insert mode, hitting backspace copies the characters on the left to the position under the cursor.

This has happened in OS X Lion, and Mountain Lion, under both Terminal.app and iTerm 2. This never happens under MacVim.

Also, I use GNU/Linux on my other machine, and have never had this happen, I am pretty sure it is strictly a Mac OS X issue, but I do not know how to fix it. For a while, I've been working around it by using MacVim most of the time, but I prefer working in a terminal.

Does anyone know what is happening here, and if so, how can I fix it?

EDIT: I tried using the macvim Vim executable, and I still get strange artefacts, but they are localized to the left side of the screen, here is an example:

[image]

Comment: What encoding do you use? In Vim and in the terminal? What is your `$TERM`? What font do you use? Does it happen when you use `nano` or some other CLI text editor? What is the version of Vim? Did you compile it? And your animated GIF doesn't seem to work embedded.

Comment: Encoding: UTF-8, $TERM=xterm-256color (in terminal) and dumb (in MacVim). Font is Inconsolata, size 18. About nano, I have not been able to reproduce the same problem in nano. Both versions of vim are 7.3. And I compiled MacVim using the homebrew package manager, but console vim is system default, I didn't compile that.

Comment: I think that Homebrew overwrites the system Vim. Are you sure that you are using the default Vim and not MacVim's CLI executable?

Comment: I am sure I am using the default vim, and not homebrew's vim. For one, `which vim` gives `/usr/bin/vim`. Also, `ls -l /usr/bin/vim` shows that it is not an alias to something in `/usr/local/bin` which is what Homebrew uses. And finally, the modified date on the `/usr/bin/vim` file is before I installed homebrew, so it is definitely the system default.

Comment: Ok, do you see the same behaviour when you use the Macvim executable in the terminal?

Comment: How do I use the macvim executable?

Comment: From the path you gave in your previous comment I'd try `$ /usr/local/bin/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim`.

Comment: I found it in `/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-65/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim`, I'll use that, and I'll update this in a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Total shot in the dark: do you have the following line in your ~/.vimrc?

```
set list listchars=tab:\ \ ,trail:
```

Try commenting it out with a `"` at the beginning of the line and restarting vim.

I picked it up from somebody's dotfiles repo and haven't had a chance to track down why it's causing problems.

I'm running iTerm2. My `$TERM` is `xterm`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to getting the Git branch to put in status line using the following function in **~/.vimrc**:

```
system("git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* //'")`
```